# Is there's a way to write a batch function to increment the value name of the registry?

Tags: batch-file, registry

I'm writing a batch file to add a new time server in windows which connects to my server(domain) and sync the device time with my server.

But in my devices, in some there are 2 time servers and in some more than 2 time servers. So I can't hard code the value name in the batch file and I need to come up with a way to get the value name from the registry(auto increment the value and assign it to the value name).

The code I wrote so far is as follows:

```
@echo off

reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/DateTime/Servers /v 3 /t REG_SZ /d 13.127.xx.xxx

net stop w32time

w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:13.127.xx.xxx

net start w32time

w32tm /config /update

w32tm /resync /rediscover

@echo Time Sync Successful

pause
```

Comment: Start with `for /f "skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %i in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DateTime\Servers"') do @echo %i,%j,%k` from an open `cmd` window (double the `%` percent sign as `%%` in a batch script).

Comment: Following @JosefZ idea you could in a batch use `for /f "skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%i in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DateTime\Servers"') do Set /A "NextSrv=%%i+1` NextSrv is the last number +1, but I'd also check if the server IP isn't already present.

Answer (score 0):

As you're already parsing the registry key from your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), you may as well use it to perform the majority of the task. This, *once you've updated the variable value on line `3`*, should:

- Leave the key untouched if the server is already listed and set as default.
- Change the server to be default if it is listed but not set as the default.
- Add the server if it isn't listed and set it to be the default server.
- Synchronise the time using the default server.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "TSvr=13.127.xx.xxx"
Set "RKey=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DateTime\Servers"
Set "#=_=0"
Set "$="
For /F "EOL=HTokens=1-2*" %%A In ('"Reg Query "%RKey%" 2>Nul|Sort"')Do (
    If "%%A"=="(Default)" (Set "DVal=%%C")Else If %%A Gtr !#! Set "#=%%A"
    If "%%C"=="%TSvr%" Set "$=%%A")
If Defined $ (If "%DVal%"=="%$%" (Echo %TSvr% is already the default server.
        GoTo End)Else (Echo %TSvr% is listed but not the currently the default.
        Echo Setting it as the default entry...
        Reg Add "%RKey%" /VE /D %$% /F>Nul 2>&1))Else (Set /A #+=1
    Echo %TSvr% is not listed.
    Echo Adding it and setting it as the default entry...
    Reg Add "%RKey%" /V !#! /D "%TSvr%">Nul 2>&1
    Reg Add "%RKey%" /VE /D !#! /F>Nul 2>&1)
SC Query state= inactive|Find "W32Time">Nul&&(Set "_=1"
    SC Start W32Time>Nul 2>&1)
Echo Synchronising the time using %TSvr%.
W32Tm /ReSync>Nul
If %ErrorLevel%==0 (Echo %TSvr% was added and your time was synchronised to it.
)Else Echo %TSvr% was added but the time was not synchronised.
:End
Pause
If Defined _ SC Stop W32Time>Nul 2>&1
EndLocal
GoTo :EOF
```